# How can I change the name of the file being saved without editing the code? MatLab

Tags: matlab, editing

I am working on an experiment that take a lot of data samples and save it to different video files. For example, I take data and save it to a file called "slowmotion.avi" and then I take another set of data and save it to another file called "normalspeed.avi".

I am trying to find a way that I could change the name of file being saved without editing the code. The way I am using right now makes me have to open the code and change the name of the file directory within the code and then save the code. I want to make it a lot faster and easier to use.

I have tried the following code to fix this problem but it doesn't work.

```
graph=input('Graph of experiment: ');
vidObj = VideoWriter('%3.1f.avi\n',graph);
.....
```

Hope I didn't confuse you.

Comment: you should write your code as a function that receives the filename as input argument.

Comment: To convert, format and concatenate strings (from integers, other strings and variables), use `sprintf` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
graph=input('Graph of experiment: ','s');
vidObj = VideoWriter([graph,'.avi']);
```

The 's' in the **input()** function indicates that the expected input is a string, and **[graph,'.avi']** simply concatenates both strings.

Comment: I have tried it but for some reason it still doesn't work. It combines the names and allows me to enter a new name for the graph but gives me this error whenever I insert a name: Error using VideoWriter 
The specified folder, graph3.avi, does not exist

Error in graphFinal (line 9)
vidObj = VideoWriter([graph,'.avi\n']);